# How to figure out a graphs function

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to time an animation in CSS, and all I have to work with is this image with some graph-plots of the animation-speed.

I did have some calculus 10 years ago, but the knowledge of deducting a function from a graph (if I ever learned that), is long gone. Can someone help me along the way please?

**Question**

What I need is a function of x to calculate y, that I can use in all three examples (they are all the same, but condenced in the x-direction).

Even though the illustration starts with 1, I guess it would be easier to have 0 as the origo as it tends to be in graphs :)

[image: Google material image-load animation (http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/imagery-treatment.html#imagery-treatment-image-load)]

Comment: Would something like $\frac1N x(b-x)e^{-ax}$ suit? [Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427evaibjuik23)...

Comment: That would be perfect! Write it out as an answer, and I'll accept it. How did you do that? :)

Comment: Your shapes could also be obtained as $ax(b-x)^n$ with $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph looks like something like 
$$
\frac1N x(b-x)e^{-ax}
$$
would suit your needs, where $N$ is a normalization factor: [$N=\frac{e^{-ab}(2+ab)+(ab-2)}{a^3}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e499aos04bk)